# PHP Composer project standard directory layout

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any standard project structure for Composer projects such as the Maven's [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in PHP?

Comment: Simple answer, "No" though it's quite common to have the code in `/src` and below, other 3rd part libraries in `/vendor`, tests in `/test`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical layout is this:

```
src/
vendor/
.git
composer.json
composer.lock
```

- For compatibility purposes, the Git and Composer files should sit in the root of the project.
- The source directory should be the root of the source files beginning with the top level namespace of your classes.
- The vendor directory should contain all third party libraries imported via composer.

This is the minimum expected standards, particularly for a live project environment.  If the project is a library, then the source directory could be omited.

The best example of this is the Symfony2 Standard Edition:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard

After this the convention for frontend assets and controller is normally:

```
web/
    js/
    css/
    images/
    index.php
```

The index file in this case is your front controller.
This should include a bootstrapper in another directory, or initialize the environment using the configuration in that directory.

For Symfony2 this is the `app` directory:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/master/app

Hope this helps, bare in mind this is based solely on my experience and observations.

Answer (score 3):

The newest answer is "yes", based on scanning every package listed on https://packagist.org and counting which directories are being used by the vast majority of packages, i.e. what most people unconsciously agreed upon without coordination:

https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton

The short summary for directories:

```
If a package has a root-level directory for ...     
                            ... then it MUST be named:
command-line executables    bin/
configuration files         config/
documentation files         docs/
web server files            public/
other resource files        resources/
PHP source code             src/
test code                   tests/
```

Using this layout pretty much aligns your project with every other project you'd probably use as dependency. Note that you do not have to have EVERY directory, only the ones that actually host files.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's a good initiative. However, Symfony structure doesn't comply with this standard.

Comment: The complete package "symfony/symfony" does, however due to the way they maintain their subcomponents it isn't feasable for them to introduce additional `src` directories in the main repository. I can live with that.